# Visual studio 2017, debug JavaScript which is loaded via dynamically loaded HTML

Tags: visual-studio-2017, javascript-debugger

It took me a while to find out why the debugging didn't work in VS2017 in this project.

*When I add the `<script>` reference in the main layout page, the debugging works fine.*

However, we also dynamically load HTML in the DOM, and in that HTML, a `<script>` tag is placed, which loads the JavaScript which is only needed for that specific part of the application.

So when the user navigates to a specific page, it loads (via Jquery) a chunck of HTML in the DOM and in that HTML a `<script>` tag loads the JavaScript files.

*But at that point, no breakpoints for those JavaScript files are hit in VS.*

Is it possible to hit those breakpoints in Visual Studio?

(I've tried the `//# sourceURL=filename.js`, which does show the file in the chrome debugging tools, but not in VS itself)